# C# permutation and combination of firstname lastname using linq or c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, c#-4.0

I tried for the below scenario for the past 1 week ,i am not able to get the logic for the below name combination scenario, i have tried in C# Linq query but its not giving the expected result so i came here for help.

below is the code i tried

```
 public List<string> NameCombination(string FnameLname, string OtherNames)
        {
            List<string> _FirstTable = new List<string>();
            List<string> _SecondTable= new List<string>();
            List<string> ResultNameCombination= new List<string>();
            string [] _FirstTableArr= FnameLname.Split(' ');
            string [] _SecondTableArr = OtherNames.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                _FirstTable.Add(_FirstTableArr[0]);
                _FirstTable.AddRange(_SecondTableArr);

                _SecondTable.Add(_FirstTableArr[1]);
                _SecondTable.AddRange(_SecondTableArr);


                var result1 =     from a in _FirstTable
                                from b in _SecondTable 
                                where a != b 
                                select a +" "+ b;

            return    ResultNameCombination=result1.ToList();
        }
```

I have scenario where i will have First name: **sue** last name : **smith** and one more column called Other names : which can be single word or two word or multiple words separated by space

now i need to make a name combination as below for the first name ,last name and other names based on below rules

1. If Other name is single word consider it  for both first name last
   name combination.(refer scenario 1 below)
2. If the Other names has two words, consider it as first name last
   name additionally to the original first name last name.(refer
   scenario 2 below)
3. If there is more than two words in other name the consider first
   word as First name and **ignore the second word as it is middle name**
   and consider  each other words as an individual  last name
   additionally to the original first name last name.(refer scenario
   3,4,5 below)

**Scenario 1: Other name is single word**

```
First name: Sue
Last Name: Smith
Other Name: Susan
```

**Name Combination Result:**

```
Sue Smith
Susan Smith
Sue Susan
```

**Scenario 2:Two Words in other names**

```
First name: Sue
Last Name: Smith
Other Name: Susan Wilson
```

**Name Combination Result:**

```
Sue Smith
Susan Wilson
Sue Wilson
Susan Smith
```

**Scenario 3:Three Words in other names**

```
First name: Sue
Last Name: Smith
Other Name: Susan con Wilson
```

**Name Combination Result:**

```
 Sue Smith
    Susan Wilson
    Sue Wilson
    Susan Smith
```

**Scenario 4 : four Words in other names**

First name: Sue
Last Name: Smith
Other Name: Susan con  kelly Wilson

**Name Combination Result:**

```
Sue Smith
Susan kelly
Susan Wilson
Sue Kelly
Sue Wilson
Susan Smith
```

**Scenario 5 : five  Words in other names**

```
First name: Sue
Last Name: Smith
Other Name: Susan con  kelly wil Wilson
```

**Name Combination Result:**

```
Sue Smith
Susan kelly
Susan Wilson
Susan Wil
Sue Kelly
Sue Wilson
Sue wil
Susan Smith
```

i need to handle the above logic in C#

Comment: Where is your code to this homework?

Comment: Have you tried something for yourself? What is not working? Could you provide code that you already tried out?

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension method to combine `IEnumerable<T>` with a single `T`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> StartWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] first) => first.Concat(rest);
```

I assume the names aren't the same to make it easier to deal with the single name case:

```
var OtherName = "Susan Wilson";
var firstName = "Sue";
var lastName = "Smith";

var otherNames = Regex.Split(OtherName, @"\s+");

var possibleFirstNames = otherNames.Take(1).StartWith(firstName);
var possibleLastNames = otherNames.Skip(otherNames.Length > 3 ? 2 : otherNames.Length-1).StartWith(lastName);

var possibleNames = (from fn in possibleFirstNames
                     from ln in possibleLastNames
                     where fn != ln
                     select fn+" "+ln).Distinct();
```